# Using IF statement in PostgreSQL to update a column that can have only 2 values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL which has a column names "value" that can accept two string values (lets say "one" and "two")
I would like to create a query that updates a row and if value column is currently "one" it updates it to be "two" and vice-versa

I've tried to the the following query:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE filename='file1' and value='one')
                      THEN UPDATE table_name SET value='two' WHERE filename='file1'
                      ELSE
                      UPDATE table_name SET value='one' WHERE filename='file1'
end if;
```

But I keep getting "syntax error at or near "IF""

Any help please?

Comment: Even if you got this to compile it wouldn't work, because it would only update the `one`s to `two` and not v.v. See Gordon's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use `if` for this.  You would use `case`:

```
update table_name
    set value = (case when value = 'one' then 'two' else 'one' end);
```

Or, if you choose to represent the binary value as a boolean, this is simpler with `not`:

```
update table_name
    set value = not value;
```